# Adding List to Database Returns Empty List

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list, sqlite

I am trying to copy a video on how to use databases, and this is the exact code from the video:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE books (title TEXT, pages INTEGER)")  

books = [
    ("Are You My Mother?", 72),
    ("The Digging-est Dog", 72),
    ("The Giving Tree", 66)
]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO books VALUES(?,?)", books)
conn.commit()
data = c.fetchall()
print(data)
```

Yet, whenever I execute the code, I get the following result:

```
[ ]
```

If anyone  could please help me and figure out why this isn't working, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: `c.fetchall()` gets the result from the previous query, which is an `INSERT` statement that doesn't return a result. Have you tried running a `SELECT * FROM books` after the `INSERT` and seeing what that returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to make sure that you use the command after you add the books to the database:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
# Then here add the output
data = c.fetchall()
print(data)
```

Hopefully this helps!!!